Long Solr query with ps and pf takes about 5 seconds to run which was about 50 ms in Solr 8
I have query similar to:
q = X AND (A OR B OR C)

Also, we use the following request handler for our solr requests:
<requestHandler name="/product-search-en" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="q">*:*</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="df">searchContent</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="fl">uniqueId,partNumber,displayName,price,rollupParentId,rollupDimensionName,productPageUrl</str>
      <str name="pf">dimensionColorValue dimensionColorValue_en tsMaterialValue tsMaterialValue_en partNumber^2.0 displayName^5.0 displayName_en^1.5 manufacturerValue_en summaryDescription_en accTypeKey^3.0 accTypeValue^3.0 accTypeValue_en^2.0 family^2 subFamily productSearchTerms^5.0 productSearchTermsSecondary searchTerms1^24 searchTerms2^12 searchTerms3^6 searchTerms4^3 searchTerms5^2 searchTerms6 basePartNumber</str>
      <str name="ps1">1</str>
      <str name="pf2">productSearchTerms~0^150 searchTerms1^100 searchTerms2^50 searchTerms3^25 searchTerms4^20 searchTerms5^10 displayName_en~2^2.0 tsMaterialValue_en^4 dimensionColorValue_en^4 accTypeValue_en^3.0</str>
      <str name="ps2">2</str>
      <str name="pf3">productSearchTerms~0^150 displayName_en~3 searchTerms1 searchTerms2 searchTerms3 searchTerms4 searchTerms5</str>
      <str name="qf">searchContent^0.25 displayName_reverse^0.5 tsMaterialValue_en dimensionColorValue_en partNumber^2.0 displayName^1.0 displayName_en^1.5 manufacturerValue manufacturerValue_en summaryDescription_en accTypeValue^2.0 accTypeValue_en^2.5 family subFamily productSearchTerms^25 productSearchTermsSecondary searchTerms1^20 searchTerms2^6 searchTerms3^3 searchTerms4^1.5 searchTerms5</str>
      
      <str name="sort">score desc</str>
      <str name="mm">3<-1<50%</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

This setup works fine in solr 8. However, in solr 9, I see the parsed query string is in MBs. We even needed to increase the max boolean clause to 50k to support this query.
I see this in solr 9 doc:

solr.xml maxBooleanClauses is now enforced recursively. Users who upgrade from prior versions of Solr may find that some requests involving complex internal query structures (Example: long query strings using edismax with many qf and pf fields that include query time synonym expansion) which worked in the past now hit this limit and fail. Users in this situation are advised to consider the complexity of their queries/configuration, and increase the value of maxBooleanClauses if warranted.

I don't understand this fully, but it seems that this change has some impact on the solr query formation. Seems odd that a query works perfectly fine in solr 8 and starts taking huge time (10x) in solr9.
Anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions what I can do here.
